# Getting advice at fiware

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wilma

I'm starting my studies at Fiware subject, however, I'm kinda lost, and I'd like to get some advice where to where to start, I've already read many articles about, but I'd like to star implement something (I already know docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know docker, then the FIWARE [Step-by-Step Tutorials](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Step-by-Step) would be a good place to start, as they demonstrate a series of simple scenarios that cover most of the open-source generic enablers found on the [FIWARE Catalogue](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue). Obviously if you want information in more depth, then the FIWARE [Academy](https://fiware-academy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) contains listing of additional materials and videos.

To start using a system in real-life, you are going to need to connect real-life IoT devices, the tutorials [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/awesome/blob/master/README.md#useful-third-party-courses) should explain how to get some comms working.

Of course, it will very much depend on the problem you set yourself to solve, but the standard layered architecture will follow the same pattern as this [Smart AgriFood](https://www.fiware.org/community/smart-agrifood/) example:

[image]

That is your devices are using some proprietary IoT protocol which is then indirectly connected to a context broker which is in turn connected to business logic and dashboards which speak NGSI. This set-up gives you total flexibility to swap in and out elements with other enablers or *FIWARE Ready* [commercial products](https://marketplace.fiware.org/) which speak NGSI.